Flutter IOS plugin shows black screen
I created a simple view controller and its Xib File for my Flutter plugin on IOS platform.
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

On my IOS plugin class I want to replace this new view controller with default view controller:
public class MyFlutterTheoryPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin { 

    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        switch call.method {
        case Constants.INITIATE_EVENTS:
            
            
            let vc = MyViewController()
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        default:
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
        
    }

But when I am running the app, I just see a black screen on the simulator.
Totally I want to show a custom native dialog on my flutter app.
